# readline with a default value

Tags: c, readline

I am able to limit the user input to 5 characters using [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html):

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int limit_rl(FILE *f)
{
    if (rl_end > 5) {
        return '\b';
    }
    return rl_getc(f);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str;

    rl_getc_function = limit_rl;
    str = readline("> ");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

But, how to read an input with a default value (not a prompt), e.g.:

```
> ummy
  ^ cursor here
```

if user types <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> return "dummy"

if user types <kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> return "mmy"

Comment: You mean `ummy` should be present already ?

Comment: Look at the `rl` example – it's possible to set a startup hook (`rl_startup_hook`) that performs an `rl_insert_text` once and then disables itself.

Comment: @ameyCU, yes, it must be present in the `rl_line buffer` and in the screen

Comment: @Jongware, works like a charm: [code](http://pastebin.com/qmGLPx2t), thanks a million!!

Comment: :) Can you post it as answer?

Comment: @Jongware, your comment seems an answer to me, post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AlterMann why are you `free(str)` ing that? Its not dynamically allocated so it doesn't need to be free'd

Comment: @Magisch, are you sure? valgrind returns a memory leak when  `free(str);` is  not used.

Comment: @Magisch: it's in the documentation: "The line `readline` returns is allocated with `malloc();` the caller should `free()` the line when it has finished with it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the homepage of `readline` a possible use is mentioned:

> `rl.c` is an example program that uses Readline to read a line of input from a user and echo it to the standard output, suitable for use by shell scripts.

and since editing an existing entry could well be part of this, I decided to take a look at its source ([direct download link](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rl.c)). This indeed shows how to insert a string into the buffer used by `readline` *before* it appears on the screen, through the use of a *hook function*:

> Variable: rl_hook_func_t * **rl_startup_hook**
>
> If non-zero, this is the address of a function to call just before `readline` prints the first prompt.
>   (https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX223)

Inside the hook function you can directly manipulate the internal buffer, for example to insert text:

> Function: int **rl_insert_text** (*const char *text*)
>
> Insert *text* into the line at the current cursor position. Returns the number of characters inserted.
>   (https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX295)

The hook function only needs to do this once (it is called only once per `readline` call inside `readline_internal_setup`), but apparently rl's author went for the belt-and-suspenders approach and specifically disables it after it has been used.

Relevant snippets from `rl.c`, comments are mine:

```
/* a global char * to hold a default initial text */
static char *deftext;

/* the callback function. The argument is supposed to be 'void' per
   its declaration:
       typedef int rl_hook_func_t (void);
   so you cannot provide the default text here */
static int set_deftext ()
{
  if (deftext)
    {
      /* Apparently the "current cursor position" in which text is inserted
         is 0, when initially called */
      rl_insert_text (deftext);
      deftext = (char *)NULL;

      /* disable the global 'rl_startup_hook' function by setting it to NULL */
      rl_startup_hook = (rl_hook_func_t *)NULL;
    }
  return 0;
}

// ...
if (deftext && *deftext)
   rl_startup_hook = set_deftext;

temp = readline (prompt);
```