# readline() function issues with printf

Tags: c, linux, printf, readline

In my C program, I use `printf` to print a formatted string to `stdout` then `readline` to get input from user with the ability to move cursor and navigate history. The issue is that if I enter a character then press backspace, the whole line, including the string printed by `printf`, gets deleted. Is there a way to fix this bad behavior? Should I report this as a bug to `readline` developers? Or should I print my formatted text to a buffer then use it as a prompt to `readline`?

A sample similar to the code:

```
...
printf("Some formatted text",...);
foo(buffer,length);
....
```

Inside foo:

```
{
...
temp=readline(NULL);
//Checking length...
...
strcpy(buffer,temp);
free(temp);
....
}
```

Comment: This is likely due to the key mapping for your terminal. See [man 3 readline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html). By default, the line editing commands are similar to those of emacs ...

Comment: You can't print to readline's input. That's just not the way stdin and stdout work. Input is input and output is output. There's no loopback. However, you can use a readline function to insert text into the readline buffer, if you do so in a callback. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346124/1566221, which I think qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: I am not intending to print to readline input using printf. printf prints to stdout and readline should read from stdin? Why does the backspace allow readline to delete what printf wrote to stdout? I will check the manpage.

Comment: I worked around the issue by writing the formatted text to an array of chars then passing it to readline's prompt argument. I updated the description because it was a bit confusing @rici

Comment: The prompt is not editable.

Comment: @rici I konw but you can edit the string before sending it to the prompt.

Comment: `readline()` expects to start at the beginning of the line. Either add a newline to the `printf()` command, or tell `readline()` about what you want at the start of the line: `readline("Some formatted text: ")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a string to appear on the *same terminal line* as the line you're entering and reading with `readline`, you should make the string the 'prompt' argument to readline.  This is difficult with the way you have things set up (the prompt printed outside of a function that calls readline), but if you can change that you can fix it:

```
char prompt[64];  // or some larger size
snprintf(prompt, sizeof(prompt), "Some formatted test", ...
foo(prompt, buffer, length);


foo(const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t length) {
  ...
  temp = readline(prompt);
  // Checking length
```