How to put default string when running scanf?
I'm wondering that is there anyway to put default string or any values when running line scanf, and the user are able to edit the deafult value.
Normal scanf:
scanf("%s", &str);

Expected scanf:
user can edit default input "abc"

scanf with default input and user able to make changes on that default input (unlike printf, user cannot make changes on printf)

Side note: scanf("%s", &str); will only read a single word. When dealing with user input, you usually want to read an entire line of input at once. For that, I recommend that you use fgets instead, and remove the trailing newline character if desired.

What you are asking for is not possible using standard C. Therefore, if you want to implement this, you will have to revert to platform-specific functionality, such as using ncurses on Linux or console functions on Microsoft Windows.

The scanf("%s", &str); is incorrect, should be scanf("%s", str);. It might not matter if the array is defined in the same scope, but if str is a function argument, it fails. It also needs a buffer size contraint otherwise is as fatal as the obsolete gets().

A simple version can be implemented with fgets(). Pressing  to accept the default, or type the new value. You can't do that with scanf() because it is impossible to enter an "empty string".

Related/possible duplicate: Allowing the user to edit text already printed on the screen in C

You can do this with the gnu readline library.

scanf does exactly what scanf is documented to do.  If you want something different write code to do it or find a library that supports it.  stdio is deliberately "primitive" so that it can be implemented on the broadest range of targets.  It is not a UI library.

The problem with your question is the answer is simply "scanf cannot do that", then you are no further forward.  Better to specify your requirements and ask how it can be done.  You will then get an answer you can use.

Not really an answer, since scanf() is the wrong tool for this job.
Instead, you should be looking at readline().
I know that is a very scary-looking function, but it can do what you want.
MIT has a page worth reading about using readline().
And our very own SO has an answer demonstrating inserting text to give a default(-ish) value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346124/2706707

Actually in C there is no direct way to do this thing but i can provide a code that you can use to address this problem.
Firstly, create a default input string then print that default input to the console after that read the user input see if it is empty if it is copy your default input to your original input string. Below code illustrates it:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char input[100];
    char defaultValue[] = "abc";
    printf("scanf here: %s", defaultValue);
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
    if (strlen(input) == 0) {
        strcpy(input, defaultValue);
    }
    printf("You entered: %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}

Here, after receiving the input using fgets function what we are doing is, we are removing the \n new line character which is automatically given by the fgets function.

This is not the problem the OP was trying to solve.

This was the 'simple' version I mentioned. It doesn't provide the ability to edit the default, and the "scanf here" cue is wrong.
